# Calculated Column left align header

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

In my list, I want a column to have a custom hyperlink.

I create a Calculated column that has the following formula.

```
="<a href='/_Layouts/tf.intranet/TFLutakastPage.aspx?LutakastId="&ID&"'>"&Title&"</a>"
```

[image]

I set the returned data type as Single line of text.

When the column renders, it renders like this.
[image]

If i set the column to render as a number, I can get the hyperlink to render correctly.

[image]

But then the problem is that the text is right aligned. Customer wants it left aligned.

I then tried changing the column formula to

```
="<DIV align=""left""><a href='/_Layouts/tf.intranet/TFLutakastPage.aspx?LutakastId="&ID&"'>"&Title&"</a></DIV>"
```

This will solve the problem with the link, but the header text is still right aligned.

[image]

How can i:

A. Get the hyperlink to render as a text field.

or

B. Leave it as a number field and left align the header column.

I'm Using Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is a bit dated, but it shows you how to properly do HTML in your calculated columns: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/

I would avoid using the number column method as your alignment issues would be impossible to fix adequately without affecting other columns.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the calculated column display format to "Date and time"  "Date Only" Option.
it will Right Align the values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work in 2010, but in 2013 the simplest (and most limited) solution is to add a CEWP to the page, click Edit Source and add css to left align the header text:

```
.ms-numHeader {text-align: left;}
```

...enclosed in style tags.  Worked for me anyway...and thanks for the tip on how to left align the calculated field!