# Calculated Column needs left alignment

Tags: column

I have the same exact problem as related here

[Calculated Column left align header](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53146/calculated-column-left-align-header)

However, the solution suggested is inadequate. This would require me to manual add the web part to each list that I create. (I'm sure you can see why this is horrible)

Is there another way to attain this by maintaining the Number type output?

Comment: Are you allowed to edit the masterpage?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

keeping the Number format, edit your formula to output something like:

```
="<span class='fixMyHead'>" & [Some field] "</span>"
```

Then, using jQuery:

```
$('.fixMyHead').each(function(){  
    $td = $(this).parents('td:first');   
    $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index()).find('.ms-numHeader').css('text-align', 'left');
    $td.children(':first').css('text-align', 'left');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way with jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class name here:contains(text in the header))').html('<div style="width:100%; text-align:left;">text for the column header</div>');
});
```

alignment now on the left.